# Fastest Way of Calculating The Length of Projection of Vector on Linear Space in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, projection

I have a linear space represented by a matrix, and their rows are not orthogonal. I would like to find the vector in another set of vectors with the shortest projection onto this linear space. I have a few algorithms for this, such as calculating the coefficients of projection as a linear combination of matrix vectors by solving a linear equation, or maximize the coefficients of projection, but what is the fastest way of doing this calculation?

Comment: Please clarify "fastest".  Is this the fastest to calculate *once* or many times?  Fastest in execution, compilation, or coding?  Least maintenance cost over time?

Comment: In any case, I don't see a tie to NumPy and Python; so far, this question is purely algebraic.

Comment: @Prune In terms of math it is simple, and it is only tied to Python due to the available numerical and optimization library (numpy, scipy, cvxpy...) available for Python. And "fastest" is defined in execution time. It can calculate once or many times, depending on whether it can calculate the projection to a linear space of a single vector or a batch of vectors.

Comment: Once vs many changes the way we approach "fastest".  If you're going to do this many times for a given matrix, it pays to find a set of basis vectors for the space.

Comment: Just compute the projection matrix once. Then compute matrix-vector products and their norms many times.